# AWS Lambda serverless fails for psycopg2 & node

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, psycopg2, serverless, serverless-framework

I have following serverless deployment yaml.

```
service: it-redshift

frameworkVersion: ">=2.72.4"

custom:
  name: data-load
  bucket: redshift-extapp
  path_prefix: 'Fulcrum'
  default_stage: dev
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:custom.default_stage}
  rs_database: master
  rs_schema: master_dbo
  rs_user: admin
  rs_port: 5439
  rs_endpoint: datawarehouse.***.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com
  rs_cluster_id: datawarehouse
  rs_region: us-west-2
  deployment-s3-bucket: it-lambda-deployments # shared bucket for all lambda functions

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.11
  region: us-west-2
  stackName: ${self:service}-${self:custom.name}-${self:custom.stage}
  stackTags:
    Service: "it"
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 900
  logRetentionInDays: 14
  # disableDefaultOutputExportNames: true
  deploymentBucket: ${self:custom.deployment-s3-bucket}
  environment:
    S3_BUCKET: ${self:custom.bucket}
    RS_DATABASE: ${self:custom.rs_database}
    RS_SCHEMA: ${self:custom.rs_schema}
    RS_USER: ${self:custom.rs_user}
    RS_PORT: ${self:custom.rs_port}
    RS_ENDPOINT: ${self:custom.rs_endpoint}
    RS_CLUSTER: ${self:custom.rs_cluster_id}
    RS_REGION: ${self:custom.rs_region}
    RS_ROLE: "arn:aws:iam::***:role/RedshiftFileTransfer"
  iam:
    role:
      name: ${self:service}-${self:custom.name}
      statements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - s3:*
          Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.bucket}/*"
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - redshift:GetClusterCredentials
            - redshift:CreateClusterUser
            - redshift:JoinGroup
          Resource: "*"

functions:
  load:
    handler: handler.run
    name: ${self:service}-${self:custom.name}
    events:
      - s3: #https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3#using-existing-buckets
          bucket: ${self:custom.bucket}
          existing: true
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          rules:
            - prefix: ${self:custom.path_prefix}/
            - suffix: data.json
          

package:
  patterns:
    - '!node_modules/**'
    - '!package*.json'
    - '!README.md'

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
```

When I try to deploy with `runtime: python3.8` or `python3.9` or `python3.10` I get

```
✖ Stack it-redshift-data-load-prod failed to deploy (0s)
Environment: darwin, node 21.4.0, framework 3.38.0 (local) 3.38.0v (global), plugin 7.2.0, SDK 4.5.1
Credentials: Local, "default" profile
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
Error: spawn python3.8 ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

Deployment works only with `runtime: python3.11` But with `python3.11` I am getting following error in the lambda

```
Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'handler': No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'
```

Comment: Error `Error: spawn python3.8 ENOENT` suggests that you don't have `python3.8` available in your system's PATH. Do you have it installed and accessible?